# Provisioning certificates error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, certificate, ios-provisioning

I have added KeyChain Access key. now There is a Problem with Provisioning certificates, It gives me the error of "Valid Signing Identity Not Found."

And When I tried to refresh from Bottom, they asked me to "Sign in with your Apple ID" and if I enter mine, It shows...

> Not on any iPhone Development Teams--> The indicated user is not on
>   any iPhone Development Teams

Is it mandatory to have the developers account to fix it or use the Provisioning certificates, actually I am using someone else Provisioning certificates and keychain certificates.

How to fix it?

Comment: If you are using someone else's certificates then try to sign in with his/her Apple ID...

Comment: no is it mandatory to enter id..it should be on developer account..

Comment: Can you add the steps in your question that you followed from the starting?

Comment: I have taken all the steps which is been required in Xcode also in code signining and build identifier..now can u tell me is it required to enter a valid developer account(paid) id in  Provisioning certificates

Comment: No, It's required only when you want to put your app on Appstore... That's why i am asking to check all the steps again.

Comment: ok.I have taken all steps 1)keychain certificate added 2)Provisional cartfc 3)bundle identifier in Xcode(removing initials after com....) 4) code signing

Comment: @BhavinChitroda I have not created any P12 or PEM file ,whats this file?? is it necessary\

Comment: I added some links in My Answer. Just go through.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the bundle identifier of the profile and put in info.plist. In Project and targets select the proper profile.IF the profile dosent match with the bundle identifier this error will come.Also check have u installed .p12 certificate for this profile in your keychain.

Comment: whats this .p12 certificate??